# Downcasting without being explicit

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a `Base` which has two child classes. `bar` creates a `unique_ptr` who's type is `Base` and attempts to initialize it with one of its child classes.

Certainly I can't downcast without being explicit of the type which I don't want to do. Are there ways around it?

```
struct Base
{

};

struct A : public Base
{
    int val;
};

struct B : public Base
{
    int val;
};

struct C : public Base
{
  // does not have val
};

void bar(bool x, int value)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr;
    if (x)
    {
        ptr = std::make_unique<A>();
    }
    else
    {
        ptr = std::make_unique<B>();
    }
    ptr->val = value;  // ERROR
}
```

Comment: You can't. Why is `val` not a member of the base class?

Comment: You need to use polymorphism: Give your base class a pure virtual getter and override it in the two derived classes. Then you can call the virtual method in bar and it will be dispatched to the derived classes

Comment: @user17732522 `num` won't be used in ALL the child classes per se (there may be additional in the future)

Comment: Btw. the code has undefined behavior because `Base` doesn't have a virtual destructor that is required when destroying the derived class object through a base class pointer as `std::unique_ptr<Base>` will do.

Comment: @xyf And what do you expect `ptr->val = value;` to do if `ptr` doesn't actually point to an object that has a `val` member in its parent object?

Comment: `A` and `B` are guaranteed to have `val` as you can see

Comment: The fact the members are of same type and have the same name is not sufficient for accessing them this way.

Comment: Ok, so this question is just about not wanting to duplicate the `ptr->val = value;` line with casts in the two cases?

Comment: @user17732522 basically

Comment: *'`A` and `B` are guaranteed to have `val`'* -- But how does `ptr` know it's not a `C`?

Comment: ...cause the casts are explicitly made for `A` and `B`

Comment: But ptr is a pointer to `Base` and you can't make any assumptions in your code on how it was initialized (from `A`, `B` or some other derived class. That's just how C++/polymorphism works. If you need to access `val` through `Base`, you have to make it part of `Base`s interface. Either by moving `val` to `Base`, or by creating a virtual getter method for `val` in `Base`.

Answer (score 3):

Types in C++ don't work this way.

If `*ptr` needs to have `val`, this must be reflected in the **static** type of `*ptr`.

In your case the static type of `*ptr` is `Base`. There is no `val` there.

Data flow analysis may prove that the **dynamic** type of `*ptr` always has `val`, but that's irrelevant. The implementation doesn't do data flow analysis. It only looks at static types.

If you need some descendants of `Base` to have `val` and others not, create an intermediate class `BaseWithVal` and work with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic lambda or helper function template to avoid code duplication:

```
void bar(bool x, int value)
{
    auto make_ptr = [&]<typename T>(){
        auto ptr = std::make_unique<T>();
        ptr->val = value;
        return ptr;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr;
    if (x)
    {
        ptr = make_ptr.operator()<A>();
    }
    else
    {
        ptr = make_ptr.operator()<B>();
    }
}
```

This requires C++20 for the explicit template parameter on the lambda. Before C++20 a helper function is easier to manage, although the following alternative also works:

```
template<typename T>
struct type_identity {
    using type = T;
};

void bar(bool x, int value)
{
    auto make_ptr = [&](auto t){
        using T = typename decltype(t)::type;
        auto ptr = std::make_unique<T>();
        ptr->val = value;
        return ptr;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr;
    if (x)
    {
        ptr = make_ptr(type_identity<A>{});
    }
    else
    {
        ptr = make_ptr(type_identity<B>{});
    }
}
```

---

But as the other answer says, if there is a need to uniformly access a subset of derived classes with a `val` member, then these should very likely share an intermediate base class with that member. That way you can simply replace `std::unique_ptr<Base>` with `std::unique_ptr<IntermediateBase>` and everything will work.

Comment: Apologies. I did not see the information from the comment and assumed he wanted extended usage of `val` with a simple syntax.

Comment: the error I am getting `reference to 'type_identity' is ambiguous`

Comment: both of your solutions don't seem to work: this is the first one -> https://godbolt.org/z/o4cTG4Kc1

Comment: @xyf The ambiguity would only happen if you use `using namespace std;` and C++20 or later, because then the standard library also has a `std::type_identity` which is what I am replicating here for C++17 and below. That's precisely why `using namespace std;` is a bad idea.

Comment: @xyf For your latest comment: You can't access `ptr->val` when `ptr` is a pointer to `Base`. That was explained in the question comments and other answer. The point of my answer is that you can move all code that requires access to `val` to the lambda where I put `ptr->val = value;` as well. That way you don't need to duplicate any code. Of course this can be done simpler using a helper function template instead of the lambda and as mentioned at the end that is not really an ideal design of the class hierarchy. https://godbolt.org/z/b78hj48e4

Comment: @user17732522 this lambda creates a unique_ptr of type T. How's `ptr` going to be used in the caller? Say `ptr` is to be passed to another function and that would be parsing `num`? What good would it be if that isn't possible

Comment: @xyf You can't do that. If you pass `ptr` on from the caller to another function, then how can this function be sure that `ptr` actually points to an object that has the member? It could be called with a pointer to any `Base`. As the comments under the question say it is impossible. That's why I asked you whether you just want to avoid code duplication in the two `if` branches, which is possible.